# how do i remove the outline on focus in DataGrid

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to remove the outline that appears when you focus on a cell in Material UI's DataGrid component.

[image: I'm trying to remove the outline that appears when you focus on a cell in Material UI's DataGrid component.]

None of these methods work:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

// Method 1:
  '@global': {
    '.MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
      outline: 0,
    },
  },

// Method 2:
  cell: {
    '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
      outline: 0,
    },
  },

// Method 3:
  cell: {
    ':focus': { outline: 0 },
  },

const classes = useStyles()

const dataGridColumns: GridColumns = [
    {
      ...other,
      cellClassName: classes.cell,
    }]
```

Edit:

```
'@global': {
        '.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
          outline: 0,
        },
      },
```

worked for me, but I would prefer not to use a global css adjustment.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using MUI >= 5, you can simply do the follow:

```
<DataGrid
   sx={{
      "&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within": {
         outline: "none !important",
      },
   }}
   ...
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This works for me with `@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.5"` while the above solutions that worked with `@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.2.2"` didnt

Comment: This worked for me as well.
Also don't forget to disable it on the column header as well:
`"&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus-within": { outline: "none",}`

Comment: If you still wish to have the outline on editable cells, the following selector will be helpful: `&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:not(.MuiDataGrid-cell--editable):focus-within`

Answer (score 15):

You can modify the MuiDataGrid-cell class by using Material UI's useStyles() function like the following (no need to declare globally):

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        '&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
            outline: 'none',
        },
    }
});

const MyComponent = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <DataGrid
           className={classes.root}
           // ...other table setup props
        />   
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Resources:

- https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core
- https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/#css
- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/420

**Edit**: Updated for 4.0.0-alpha.29

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        '&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus, &.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
            outline: 'none',
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: I added more details about the setup to provide additional clarity. If this does not work for you, could you provide more details in your question about your DataGrid component setup?

Answer (score 10):

Just for completion sake this is how I styled the DataGrid with styled components and it worked.

```
const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)`
  &.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus,
  &.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(
      () => createStyles({
        root: {
          '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus-within, & .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within': {
            outline: 'none',
          },

          '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader:focus, & .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
            outline: 'none',
          },
        },
      }),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

I use createTheme to manage it like so:

```
{ createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import type {} from '@mui/x-data-grid/themeAugmentation';

export const theme = createTheme({
  ...
   components: {
     MuiDataGrid: {
       styleOverrides: {
         root: {
          '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
            outline: 'none'
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within': {
            outline: 'none'
          }
        },
       }
     }
   }
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do this as well for a project I'm working on.

You can override many of the classes used by the datagrid, but you'll need to make sure that the selector being used is more specific in order for it to take precedence.

Many of their classes are documented [here](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/) in the CSS section.

The below snippet worked for me.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiDataGrid-root": {
      "& .MuiDataGrid-colCell:focus": {
        outline: "none"
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way for me was add this code to your css file:

```
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader,
.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

I found that if we set it just for :focus, then if we click to a button of cell, outline still visible

Answer (score 0):

I'm  using version 6 and noticed that, when trying the suggestions in the answers, the blue outline sometimes reappeared. The below code permanently resolved that:

```
import { gridClasses } from '@mui/x-data-grid';


<DataGrid
   sx={{
     [`& .${gridClasses.cell}:focus, & .${gridClasses.cell}:focus-within`]:
        {
         outline: 'none',
        },
     [`& .${gridClasses.columnHeader}:focus, & .${gridClasses.columnHeader}:focus-within`]:
        {
          outline: 'none',
        },
   }}
```

To give an idea, this example uses the paid version but it also works for the free version - just change the import as per above :
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/objective-keller-sqsqhl?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx