# How to remove cell border in Data Grid component of Material-Ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm implementing a table with the data grid component.[Data Grid - Material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/#mit-version)

Every cell, when clicked, receives this border, how do I remove it?

[image]

```
<DataGrid
  disableSelectionOnClick={true}
  className={classes.main}
  classes={classes.main}
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={5}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[5,10,15]}
  checkboxSelection={true}
  disableColumnSelector
  disableDensitySelector
  onCellClick={click}
  disableColumnFilter
  disableColumnMenu
/>
```

I don't want to remove the cell, I want the border not to appear when I click on the cell

Comment: have you tried `*:focus { outline: none;}` using a css?

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607099/how-do-i-remove-the-outline-on-focus-in-datagrid

Answer (score 19, accepted):

apply this code on css and make sure to import css on react component

```
    .MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @muhammad-dahari. For such questions, a js-fiddle link in the answer is helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I used this answer and put it in the "sx" as '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within'  property on the DataGrid. I didn't need to use !important.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to accomplish this with styledcomponents by simply pasting the css in a styled component.